# Specify font size in webview via dip

Tags: android

Is there a way to programmatically convert dip to px as I need to set a font size in a webview but dip will be no good I am assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of Density-independent pixel (dp) from [Overview of Screens Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

> The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels.

I'm not sure how well that will work for you in a `WebView` but worth looking at.

Comment: is there an easy way to convert from dip to px?

Comment: @Max: The calculation above is quite easy. What don't you understand about it?

Comment: sorry I should have explained clearer. I have this running now this should explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207701/converting-from-dip-to-px