# Converting from dip to px

Tags: android

I currently have this running with the stack output below as it is throwing up an error.

```
    Resources r = getResources();
    float pix = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14, r.getDisplayMetrics());

> Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.pne/com.test.pne.one}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xe
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xe
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:205)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2809)
at com.quiz.max.Quiz.onCreate(Quiz.java:87)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even really see what your question is, but the error seems as though it's caused by a String resource that isn't being found (Maybe try Fixing Android project properties?)

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xe at
```

Maybe if you explain more what you want, I can try to help more.

Comment: im trying to convert 14 dip into its relative pixel value.

Comment: it was because i was trying to settext as an integer not string. thank you for pointing it out.